# Powershell group member ship field from AD

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory

I have a powershell query here which look in a particular group in AD and extracts the users into a CSV. Currently it only extracts the SamAcountName and Display name. How would I get it extract the group membership of each user in that group ?

```
 Get-ADGroupMember -identity GLS-IW-APP-QV-KPI-Full   | select -Property Name,SamAccountName | Export-csv -path X:\QlikView_AD_Groups\GLS-IW-APP-QV-KPI-Full.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you are looking to get the group membership of all users in a certain group this would be one approach. You need to add a calculated propery in your `Select-Object`

```
Get-ADGroupMember -identity GLS-IW-APP-QV-KPI-Full | 
        Select-Object -Property Name,SamAccountName,@{Label="MemberOf";Expression={(Get-ADUser -identity $_.SamAccountName -Properties memberof).memberof -Join ";"}} | 
        Export-csv -path X:\QlikView_AD_Groups\GLS-IW-APP-QV-KPI-Full.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

What the `@{}` portion does is take the `SamAccountName` and call Get-Aduser to extract the memberof property. Since that returns an object we concat that to a semicolon delimited string with a `-Join` for proper/better CSV output